# jQuery auto complete adding escape characters to the results ater arrow up or down

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

Have a look here:

http://jsfiddle.net/zK3Wc/27/

Does anyone have a quick and simple fix for this?

Basically the html escape characters are being added in the input field if the user arrows up, or down.

Comment: I'm not seeing this in Chrome.

Comment: Just checked it in Chrome and the problem is there.. Start typing jQuery, then use your ARROWS to arrow up - and look what gets pushed into the text input.  Unescaped html characters..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

http://jsfiddle.net/zK3Wc/32/

With the help of some googling and another S.O. Question; under the "focus" object, I added this:

```
        $( ".project" ).val( ui.item.label );
        function decode(input){
          return $('<div/>').html(input).text();
        }
        $(function(){
          $('.project').keydown(function(){
            $($(this)).val(decode($($(this)).val()));
          });
        });
```

Hopefully this helps anyone else that runs into this problem!

Tested in IE 7,8,9 FF, Chrome and Safari.

Answer (score 1):

In your `projects` array, you have unicode character references. If your website is encoded as UTF-8, this may not be necessary.

See here:  http://jsfiddle.net/zK3Wc/28/

Comment: I see what you did there! But unfortunately, all of the text I'm working with has the html escape characters already there. To go back and change those now isn't possible. It's handled by a 3rd party.

Comment: Ick. You're going to have to parse and replace. Or you can take the Google Search approach and use a Div element to display the selection instead of an input field.